# javascript getElementsByClassName not working on multiple input

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement google city names. My code is

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&libraries=places"></script>
    <script>
            function init() {
                var input = document.getElementsByClassName('place');
                var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

            }

            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);

        </script>
```

I have many forms on the page with muliple instances of input 'place'

```
<input type="text" class="place"  name="femaleplace" placeholder="Place of Birth" required>
<input type="text" class="place"  name="maleplace" placeholder="Place of Birth" required>
```

However nothing works. When I have only one instance of input 'place' on the page, getElementById works fine.

Comment: Yes it would not working like this, you have to each loop for iterating

Comment: you have to be specific which number of the class you want to select i.e. `document.getElementsByClassName("place")[0]` would select `femaleplace`

Comment: [The documentation](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-widget#Autocomplete) says `Autocompletion` expects `HTMLInputElement`, you're passing a [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection).

Answer (score 0):

```
 document.getElementsByClassName('className');
```

returns a `nodeList` of all the elements with that className. The Autocomplete cannot complete `with` n number of element values. When n=1 it works but for more than that it won't.

Answer (score 0):

`Autocomplete` constructor is expecting a single element parameter and you are providing an array of elements.

Note that get**Elements**ByClassName is returning an array of elements while get**Element**ById is returning a single element. That explains why you get it working when you use `getElementById`

If you want it working using `getElementsByClassName` you will need to loop through every element

Answer (score 0):

this worked

```
function init() {
      var input = document.getElementsByClassName('place');
      for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input[i]);
}
}
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
```

Answer (score -1):

Your `input` variable is an array of HTMLCollection, not a single one. I supper the correct version of your code is:

```
 function init() {
      var input = document.getElementsByClassName('place');
      input.forEach(function(i){
           var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(i);
           //do more stuff with autocomplete
     });
}
```

Comment: "_input variable is an array of HTMLelements_" No, it isn't, did you try the code?